# Loopback: How can we modify the return data of a built in model function

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopback

I created a model named member inherited from the built in model User,
But how can I change the format of the login return. ie,

currently the invalid login is returning like

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "login failed",
    "code": "LOGIN_FAILED",
    "stack": "Error: login failed\n ..."
  }
}
```

I want to change like,

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "login failed",
    "code": "LOGIN_FAILED",
    "stack": "Error: login failed\n ..."
}
```

Also, the success case as well,

ie current return is

```
{
  "id": "P1jAavmCRbiYB1gYaE2snj3I6BayIYOCJ7HsTLeF1bezlEGVAUzjwdxKB5QFH9Vu",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2017-02-02T13:19:05.709Z",
  "userId": "5885b186db6df92d3ada7777"
}
```

I want to change like,

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "name": "Success",
  "token": "P1jAavmCRbiYB1gYaE2snj3I6BayIYOCJ7HsTLeF1bezlEGVAUzjwdxKB5QFH9Vu",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2017-02-02T13:19:05.709Z",
  "userID": "5885b186db6df92d3ada7777"
}
```

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `strong-error-handler` from middlewares and add your custom error handler like [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-middleware.html#error-handling-middleware)

In `config.json` you need to do :

```
...
"remoting" {
  ...
  "handleErrors": false
  ...
}
...
```

Also create `config.local.js` in root/sever folder and add below :

```
'use strict';

var errorConverter = require('./middlewares/error-converter');

module.exports = {
  remoting: {
    errorHandler: {
      handler: errorConverter()
    }
  }
};
```

`error-converter.js` in middleare folder (or any other place) is the custom error hadnling middleare

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Cool, you're welcome. So please kindly accept the answer

Comment: But on removing strong-error-handler from middleware, unable to start the server: (Error: The middleware "strong-error-handler" in phase "final:after"is not defined in the main config)

Comment: Can you tell, how can we handle the success login condition as well like this, is for changing the return format of success login?

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Please tell me specific for changin the result of the login

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Add after remote hook for that method and change what you want. And the boot script is the best place for that